# How to connect to an existing postgreSQL database in a new Blazor Server Web App?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0, npgsqlconnection

I try to scaffold `DbContext` using this line in package manager console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "host=xx.xx.xx.xxx port=xxxx dbname=postgres user=xxxx password=xxxx sslmode=prefer connect_timeout=10 sslcert=<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.crt sslkey=<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.key" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -OutputDir Models
```

and i get this exeption:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x00002AF9) No such host known
```

i have installed the following packages first:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Am i supposed to setup the connection string in `appsettings.json` first and add `dbcontext` to `builder.Services` before scaffolding?

Comment: It should be  `Scaffold-DbContext  -connection "your connection string"`

Comment: i did this:
    `'PM> Scaffold-DbContext -connection "DefaultConnection"`

this is my appsettings.json:
    `{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=5432;Database=postgres;Username={USERNAME};password={PASSWORD};Trust Server Certificate=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}`

i get this exception:
    Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: Try : `Scaffold-DbContext  -connection "Host=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=username;password=password;Trust Server Certificate=true;"`